# How can the model be tuned to improve precision, when precision is much more important than recall?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

The performance of a machine learning classifier can be measured by a variety of metrics like precision, recall, and classification accuracy, among other metrics.

Given code like this:

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

1. What metric is the fit function trying to optimze?
2. How can the model be tuned to improve precision, when precision is much more important than recall?

Answer (score 4):

You can tune parameters of your SVM by using [Grid Search Cross Validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV) to maximize your precision. To do so, set the parameter "scoring" like

```
sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid, scoring="precision")
```

Here `clf` is your SVC classifier and, of course, you you also need to set the grid of parameters `param_grid`. See examples [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/randomized_search.html#example-model-selection-randomized-search-py)

Comment: I'm not sure how good an idea this is, as you can get 100% by setting the threshold appropriately... Probably that won't happen, still not that principled.

Comment: @Andreas Mueller Sure, there are several _strategies_ on improving model performance. This is the actual work you are doing when exploring your dataset. Without any info about the dataset, I think, this question is about the scikit-learn API.

Answer (score 3):

1. As far as I know, SVMs minimize the hinge loss.
2. I'm not aware of any general-purpose way to make a support vector classifier prioritize precision over recall. As always, you can use cross validation and then play with the hyperparameters to see if anything helps. Alternatively, you could train a regressor outputting a value in [0,1] instead of a classifier. Then, by choosing a proper threshold such that you put all examples getting a score above that threshold into category '1', you get a classifier with a tunable threshold parameter which you can set arbitrarily high to maximize precision over recall.

Answer (score 3):

I see two ways: optimizing by grid-searching for parameters, as @laneok suggests, or optimizing by adjusting a threshold as @cfh suggests.

Optimally you should do both.

I would not try to only optimize precision, as you usually get 100% precision by setting a very high threshold and getting very low recall. So if possible, you could define a trade-off between precision and recall that you like, and grid-search over that.

You can probably get better results for that if you actually do pick a separate threshold. You can use the SVC.decision_function to get a continuous output, and then pick the optimum threshold for the tradeoff you want to achieve. To pick the threshold you would need a validation set, though, which makes doing this inside the grid-search a bit more tricky (not impossible, though).

What I usually find is a good trade-off between optimizing what you want and complexity of pipeline is to optimize in the grid-search for something that will take precision into account, say "roc_auc", and after the grid-search pick a threshold on a validation set based on the tradeoff you like.

roc_auc basically optimizes for all possible thresholds simultaneously, so the parameters will not be as specific for the threshold you want as they could be.

Comment: You are right, though you would get NaN precision if you never predict anything. Fixed my answer.

Comment: fell free. Your comment was definitely valuable ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a technique where you can write you own loss function to focus on the ranking metrics like(AUC, Precision-Recall) rather than the classification losses like(hinge loss or log-loss).

Refer section 4( Maximizing Recall at Fixed Precision) of the paper
Scalable Learning of Non-Decomposable Objectives (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.04802.pdf) for more details.